# Logo on the home page is located at a different place than on other pages

Tags: css, magento

I am a newbie still.

I am using Magento CE 1.4.1.1  For some reason the logo on the home page is little to the right than logo on all the other pages.  I tried to use CSS to modify the padding and margin on the header, but whatever I do, the position of the logo is different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your hompage looks like this:

```
 <h1 class="logo">
    <strong>Hapiru</strong>
    <a href="http://www.hapiru-usa.com/index.php/" title="Hapiru" class="logo">
      <img src="https://www.hapiru-usa.com/skin/frontend/default/MAGFREE001Hb/images/logo.gif" alt="Hapiru">
    </a>
 </h1>
```

Your other page looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.hapiru-usa.com/index.php/" title="Hapiru" class="logo">
  <strong>Hapiru</strong>
  <img src="https://www.hapiru-usa.com/skin/frontend/default/MAGFREE001Hb/images/logo.gif" alt="Hapiru">
</a>
```

I think that the difference could come from using two different templates. Can you figure out which which templates you're using for the homepage (the homepage is a CMS page so it would be there, whereas other pages' layouts will probably be in `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout`

I think if you get the pages to use the same templates that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I found that many of the free themes seem to have this problem.  For some reason, the header.phtml adds a h1 tag if it is a homepage and leaves the h1 tag out, if it is not a homepage.  I fixed it by commenting out the h1 tag.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The logo on your home page is within an <h1></h1> tag, but not so on your other pages--could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS style of the logo must be overlapping with another one which is also assigning padding/margin. Use the identical CSS style for both cases and you'll get the same results. If you use the first one with h1 class="logo" you'll get it moved to the right and if you use the 2nd one, you'll get it as you want it. Investigate the CSS for h1 tag and for logo class, that's where the problem is located. It could even be an issue that the h1 tag is having a padding and the logo class does not, but still the padding from h1 tag applies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `#logo h1 { padding-left:0;}`